# Why in this code it is used the RxJS pipe() operator to encapsulate a single map() operator and not to chain multiple RxJS operators?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am not so into RxJs. I am following an Angular video course based on Angular+RxJS and I have the following doubt. Basically it creates a service class that call a REST API returning a JSON like this:

```
{
   "payload":[
      {
     "id":1,
     "description":"Serverless Angular with Firebase Course",
     "longDescription":"Serveless Angular with Firestore, Firebase Storage & Hosting, Firebase Cloud Functions & AngularFire",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/serverless-angular-small.png",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":6,
     "url":"serverless-angular",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":2,
     "description":"Angular Core Deep Dive",
     "longDescription":"A detailed walk-through of the most important part of Angular - the Core and Common modules",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/angular-core-in-depth-small.png",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":3,
     "url":"angular-core-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":3,
     "description":"RxJs In Practice Course",
     "longDescription":"Understand the RxJs Observable pattern, learn the RxJs Operators via practical examples",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/rxjs-in-practice-course.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/main-logo/main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "seqNo":2,
     "url":"rxjs-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":4,
     "description":"NgRx (with NgRx Data) - The Complete Guide",
     "longDescription":"Learn the modern Ngrx Ecosystem, including NgRx Data, Store, Effects, Router Store, Ngrx Entity, and Dev Tools.",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-university.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/course-images/ngrx-v2.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "seqNo":1,
     "url":"ngrx-course",
     "promo":false,
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":5,
     "description":"Angular for Beginners",
     "longDescription":"Establish a solid layer of fundamentals, learn what's under the hood of Angular",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/angular2-for-beginners-small-v2.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/main-logo/main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "seqNo":4,
     "url":"angular-for-beginners",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":6,
     "description":"Angular Security Course - Web Security Fundamentals",
     "longDescription":"Learn Web Security Fundamentals and apply them to defend an Angular / Node Application from multiple types of attacks.",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/security-cover-small-v2.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/lock-v2.png",
     "category":"ADVANCED",
     "lessonsCount":11,
     "seqNo":9,
     "url":"angular-security-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":7,
     "description":"Angular PWA - Progressive Web Apps Course",
     "longDescription":"Learn Angular Progressive Web Applications, build the future of the Web Today.",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/angular-pwa-course.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/alien.png",
     "category":"ADVANCED",
     "lessonsCount":8,
     "seqNo":10,
     "url":"angular-pwa-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":8,
     "description":"Angular Advanced Library Laboratory: Build Your Own Library",
     "longDescription":"Learn Advanced Angular functionality typically used in Library Development. Advanced Components, Directives, Testing, Npm",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/advanced_angular-small-v3.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/angular-advanced-lesson-icon.png",
     "category":"ADVANCED",
     "seqNo":11,
     "url":"angular-advanced-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":9,
     "description":"The Complete Typescript Course",
     "longDescription":"Complete Guide to Typescript From Scratch: Learn the language in-depth and use it to build a Node REST API.",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/typescript-2-small.png",
     "courseListIcon":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/typescript-2-lesson.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":12,
     "url":"typescript-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":11,
     "description":"Angular Material Course",
     "longDescription":"Build Applications with the official Angular Widget Library",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/material_design.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":14,
     "url":"angular-material-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":12,
     "description":"Angular Testing Course",
     "longDescription":"In-depth guide to Unit Testing and E2E Testing of Angular Applications",
     "iconUrl":"https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/angular-testing-small.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":5,
     "url":"angular-testing-course",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "promo":false,
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":14,
     "description":"NestJs In Practice (with MongoDB)",
     "longDescription":"Build a modern REST backend using Typescript, MongoDB and the familiar Angular API.",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-university.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/course-images/nestjs-v2.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "seqNo":8,
     "url":"nestjs-course",
     "promo":false,
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":16,
     "description":"Stripe Payments In Practice",
     "longDescription":"Build your own ecommerce store & membership website with Firebase, Stripe and Express",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-university.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/course-images/stripe-course.jpg",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "seqNo":7,
     "url":"stripe-course",
     "price":50
      },
      {
     "id":17,
     "description":"Reactive Angular Course",
     "longDescription":"How to build Angular applications in Reactive style using plain RxJs - Patterns and Anti-Patterns",
     "iconUrl":"https://angular-university.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/course-images/reactive-angular-course.jpg",
     "courseListIcon":"https://angular-academy.s3.amazonaws.com/main-logo/main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
     "category":"BEGINNER",
     "lessonsCount":10,
     "seqNo":0,
     "url":"reactive-angular-course",
     "price":50
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see it contains a **payload** property containing n objects. The tutorial show as, starting from the Observable emitting this **payload** property  it will return another Observable that emit only the array.

This is the proposed solution:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoursesService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  loadedAllCourses(): Observable<Course[]> {
    // The obsarvable return a JSON containing the "payload" property containing the array
    //return this.http.get<Course[]>("/api/courses");
    return this.http.get<Course[]>("/api/courses")
          .pipe(
            map(res => res["payload"])
          );


  }

}
```

Now I know that the **map()** operator works on an Observable and return another Observable "modified" by the arrow function passed to the origianl Observable (in this case I am accesing to the content of the **payload** field of the API call response and I am creating a new Observable containing only the **payload** field content. It is clear.

The thing that I can not understand is: why this **map()** operator is defined inside a **pipe()** operator. From what I understood reading the official documentation the **pipe()** operator is used to chain multiple operators in declarative fashion (so for example: apply OPERATOR 1, on the output of the OPERATOR 1 (that is an Observable) apply OPERATOR 2 and return another Observable and so on.

Is this reasoning correct? In the previous case I only have a **map()** operator so in theory I can use the **map()** operator directly on the Observable returned by the **get()** method (directly on the Observable containing the API response). Is it right?

Why in this course the istructor always use the **pipe()** operator also when only a single operator is applied? (as in the previous case). Is it a sort of convention or is it an "error"?

Comment: There are at least two distinct questions here. Your intuition is correct. The following is valid `map(x => x.payload)(myObservable$)`. Why don't most people use that form for applying a single operator? I would argue it's because it reduces readability by employing a different syntax for the unary case, makes adding an additional operator inconvenient, and most importantly because of how the rxjs API evolved over time from fluent method calls to a functional pipeline. As you say, that's a convention. It should be noted that your use of types is incorrect in that would be the other question...

Comment: @AluanHaddad Tnx, why did you said that  the use of types is incorrect?

Comment: @AndreaNobili With `this.http.get<Course[]>("/api/courses")` you specify that this http request returns `Course[]`. But `res` is not of type `Course[]`, `res[payload]` is.

Comment: @fridoo thank you. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

In this course the instructor always use the pipe() operator because starting from RxJs 6 they use pipeable operators and that goes from official documentation - https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators.

Regarding the way how you use map, seems like "pluck" operator is more appropriate for your case:

```
   this.http.get<Course[]>("/api/courses")
    .pipe(
        pluck("payload")
    );
```

Comment: This is not answering the question. The question wants to know whether that is in fact a matter of correctness or of convention and perhaps why. If you try to actually answer the question, you could learn a fair amount